# CKEditor changes tag order

Tags: ckeditor

CKEditor transforms the follow html code :

```
<a><h1>H1</h1></a>
```

to

```
<h1><a>H1</a></h1>
```

How to prevent CkEditor doing that change ?

My configuration :

```
allowedContent : true;
```

Snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CKEditor</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.9/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea name="editor1"><a href="#"><h1>Title</h1></a></textarea>
        <script>
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' , {
       uiColor: '#ff0000',
       allowedContent: true
            });
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the answer is that there's no solution. Block level links (like `a` wrapping `h1`) are not supported by ckeditor, at last not yet. You can check this [dev ticket](https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9457) for updates.

Comment: Thank for the information, but we can note that the following code works : <a href="#"><img /> <span>B</span></a>

Comment: I suppose that's because `img` has to be wrapped by an `a`, and a `span` is an inline element, not a block element like `h1` or `div`.

Comment: OK that makes sense